# Finding old gramps data on my computer

Tags: gramps

I used gramps to work with my family genealogy information years ago, but I haven't touched it since 2016, and did most of the work in 2012. I cannot find where it's storing the old information.

Will I have to start over, or is there somewhere I can find where it was storing everything?

This was at least one computer ago.

Comment: It will be in usual directory on that old computer.  It is only in the cloud if you put it there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE! Do you still have your old computer? How did you transfer your files from the old (or older) computer to your current one?

Answer (score 4):

This could be tricky if you do not have a version of gramps running on your current computer, and it likely is going to be different for different operating systems. On my windows system I have a folder "Gramps" with a subfolder "grampsdb" that contains a pile of .db files. You should be able to search for that. These database files are in binary format and cannot be read directly by humans... You can tell gramps where your files are located: Under Edit > Preference > Family tree you can specify the directory. If that is not the directory where your version of Gramps would normally search, you can direct it there. (If you have/had several trees, there will be a separate folder for each tree.)

Final thought; Whatever you do, make absolutely sure to BACK UP your data before you install gramps.